# labelling different lines on split operation

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, timelion

I am using split on 1 of my fields.

It is split into different lines.

[image]

If I use `.label('something')`, then each line has the same name. but I want to give each line a different name.

How to label each line with different name ?

Answer (score 11):

You need to use the regex functionality of `.label`

Try this:

```
.label("Ride ID: $1", "^.* > ride_id:(.+) > .*")
```

The `$1` will be replaced by the first argument in the regex, `ride_id:(.+)` so you should end up your key labels as:

```
Ride ID: 4
Ride ID: 54
Ride ID: 5
Ride ID: 14
Ride ID: 50
```

Comment: Works wonderfully. Here is my application of the example: 
`.label(label="$1", regex="^.* > app.keyword:(.+) > .*")` (v.6.5.4)